# jquery.quickWizard - how to introduce step counting above the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, wizard

I've created a wizard from a long form with a help of [jquery.quickWizard plugin](https://github.com/conzett/jquery.quickWizard). One of the good things about this plugin that it works with  jquery.validate which is really handy.
 Now i need to display current step(in the wizard) above the form, are there ready to use solutions for that?